# Create Pandas columns from where clause and get mean from categorical values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

These are the first five rows of my dataframe:

```
City    Edition NOC Medal
Athens  1896    HUN Gold
Athens  1896    AUT Silver
Athens  1896    GRE Bronze
Athens  1896    GRE Gold
Athens  1896    GRE Silver
```

I want to create a new table that will be grouped by `NOC` and the other two columns will be `Average Before 1996` and and the other will be `Average After 1996` according to the `Edition` column. It would look something like this (all values are placeholders):

```
NOC Average Before 1996  Average After 1996
USA     30              40
URS     25              30
GBR     50              20
```

My difficulty is that I can create a total count for each country:

```
total_medal_count = olympics_df.groupby('NOC')\
                               .Medal.count()\
                               .reset_index(name="Medal_Count")\
                               .sort_values("Medal_Count", ascending=False)

NOC Medal_Count
USA 4334
URS 2049
GBR 1594
```

However, I can't get the averages for specific values in the `Edition` column.

I tried the following:

```
total_medal_count['Before 1996'] = np.mean(total_medal_count.Medal_Count).where(olympics_df['Edition'] < 1996)
```

But this doesn't work because I can't pull `where` from a mean. I would probably also have problems referencing one dataframe in the `np.mean` function and another in the `where` function.

Comment: there is no `USA` in your source data, nor is there any 1996. kindly fit your expected dataframe to match the contents of your source dataframe

Comment: I changed my description to reflect that those are just the first 5 lines of the source

Comment: I mentioned that my sample dataframe was just the first five rows, therefore there's no way for readers to know if my expected output is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the dataframe using `gt` operator with the desired year. Create a new dataframe with all unique `NOC` values as index, this way, any non-existing value in the next step will already be accounted for. Use `groupby` for each portion of the split dataframe. Then, use `apply` with the function that counts the unique values ([`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html)) of `Edition` and average those values for each `NOC`.

Input *sample.csv*

```
  City  Edition  NOC   Medal
Athens     1993  GRE    Gold
Athens     1994  AUT  Silver
Athens     1994  GRE  Bronze
Athens     1994  GRE    Gold
Athens     1994  GRE  Silver
Athens     1997  GRE  Silver
Athens     1998  HUN    Gold
Athens     1998  AUT  Silver
Athens     1998  GRE  Bronze
Athens     1998  HUN    Gold
Athens     1998  AUT  Silver
Athens     1998  GRE  Bronze
Athens     2001  GRE    Gold
Athens     2002  GRE  Silver
Athens     2003  HUN    Gold
```

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', sep='\s+')

gt1996 = df['Edition'].gt(1996)
le1996 = ~gt1996

avg_medals = lambda x: x['Edition'].value_counts().mean()

dr = pd.DataFrame(index=df['NOC'].unique())
dr['Average Before 1996'] = df[le1996].groupby('NOC').apply(avg_medals)
dr['Average After 1996'] = df[gt1996].groupby('NOC').apply(avg_medals)

print(dr)
```

Output from *dr*

```
     Average Before 1996  Average After 1996
GRE                  2.0                1.25
AUT                  1.0                2.00
HUN                  NaN                1.50
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what need you?

Observation: I have added one row to test (second row).

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
 ['Athens',  1896,    'HUN', 'Gold']
  ,['Athens',  1000,    'HUN', 'Gold']
,['Athens',  1997,    'HUN', 'Gold']
,['Athens',  1896,    'AUT', 'Silver']
,['Athens',  1896,    'GRE', 'Bronze']
,['Athens',  1896,    'GRE', 'Gold']
,['Athens',  1896,    'GRE', 'Silver']
]

#Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['City','Edition','NOC','Medal'])

aux_df = df.groupby(by ='NOC')['Edition'].mean().reset_index();

aux_df['Average Before 1996'] = aux_df['NOC'].apply(lambda x: df[(df.NOC == x) & (df.Edition<=1996)].groupby(by ='NOC')['Edition'].mean().reset_index()['Edition'].sum())
aux_df['Average After 1996'] = aux_df['NOC'].apply(lambda x: df[(df.NOC == x) & (df.Edition>1996)].groupby(by ='NOC')['Edition'].mean().reset_index()['Edition'].sum())

aux_df['Count Before 1996'] = aux_df['NOC'].apply(lambda x: df[(df.NOC == x) & (df.Edition<=1996)].groupby(by ='NOC')['Medal'].count().reset_index()['Medal'].sum())
aux_df['Count After 1996'] = aux_df['NOC'].apply(lambda x: df[(df.NOC == x) & (df.Edition>1996)].groupby(by ='NOC')['Medal'].count().reset_index()['Medal'].sum())


#print(df.groupby(by ='NOC').mean())

print(aux_df.to_string())
```

[image]

Comment: The ```Average Before 1996``` and ```Average After 1996``` in your answer are averages of ```Edition``` and not of ```Medal```. What I need is the average medals won by each country pre 1996 and post 1996.